# Reverse Sentences in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reverse, sentence

```
function reverserStr(str){
   let word = str.split("").reverse().join("");
   return word;
}
console.log(reverserStr("I eat banana"));
```

what I expect is "banana eat I", while what I'm getting here is "ananab tae I", not sure what is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are splitting with `""`, you are getting an array of all the characters in the string which is being reversed. You should split with space character (`" "`):

```js
function reverserStr(str){
   let word = str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
   return word;
}
console.log(reverserStr("I eat banana"));
```